CrudField JavaScript Library with relationship/subfield fields
I have a crud with a relationship type and subfields:
'name'  => 'serviceProvider',
'type'  => 'relationship',
'label' => 'Services Provider',
'subfields'   => [
    [
        'name'  => 'cost',
        'label' => 'Cost',
        'type'  => 'number',
        'attributes' => ["step" => "any"], // allow decimals
        'wrapper' => [
            'class' => 'form-group col-sm-4'
        ],
    ],
    [
        'name'  => 'is_no_tarif_cost',
        'label' => 'Cost without tarif',
        'type'  => 'checkbox',
        'wrapper' => [
            'class' => 'form-group col-sm-2 d-flex align-items-end'
        ],
    ],
]

and I want to make it so that when the field is_no_tarif_cost is changed, a console log of the changed rowNumber
crud.field('serviceProvider').subfield('is_no_tarif_cost').onChange(function(field) {
    console.log('hey i am here on row: ' + field.rowNumber) 
});

I did everything according to the documentation, but it doesn't work. No JavaScript errors in the console. It's as if the hook is being hung on the wrong object. Any ideas what the error might be?

Can you View-Source on your webpage, and check that the javascript is properly there ?

@PedroX, Yes, the JS is placed where it should be. In addition to the code with this functionality, I have other logic implemented in the JS file on other elements. Everything works correctly except for this part.

I'm able to get the message on the console with your exact code.

What I did:

Add script via Widget

protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
  Widget::add()->type('script')->content('assets/js/test.js');
 ... 
}


Code inside script

crud.field('postalboxes').subfield('postal_name').onChange(function (field) {
  console.log('hey i am here on row: ' + field.rowNumber)
});


Thanks for the answer. I have everything done exactly the same, but the console log does not work. Can you show your HTML layout?
